# The method addListener(SessionListener) is undefined for the type ServletContext

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

Undefined symbol error in `addListener(SessionListener)` method. Here is my snippet:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);       
    servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
}
```

My Maven dependency:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId> 
    <version>3.1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

what's your servlet-api version?

I use javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar , it has this method.

Comment: My Dependency is

         <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

This method addListener is new in 3.0.0 version, probably you have in your a application a old version of ServletContext for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You need to exclude this from your project, you can do this with exclusion tag inside the dependency who is using this servlet jar.

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```